# How to write sym sum $i^\text{th}$ in $\text{MATLAB}$?

Tags: summation, matlab

How to write the function below in *MATLAB*?

Having hard time to express $i^\text{th}$ in sym sum. Trying to minimize $x$ for the optimization, so $f(x)$ is the objective function.
$$
 f_0(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\log(x_i).
$$

Comment: what is the relationship between $x$ and the RHS? What does $x_i$ mean here? Is $x$ possibly a vector? Where are you getting stuck, can you compute $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$?

Comment: yes x is a vector. trying to minimize x for the optimization

Comment: Can you write code to compute $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$?

Answer (score 0):

Vectorised operations in *MATLAB* are a really good practise if you want to evaluate that sum fast.

Let $x$ denote the vector $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$. You can do it as follows

```
f0 = sum(x.*log(x))
```

Comment: That's not completely right because you are just multiplying elementwise the vectors. I think you'll correct that. :-)

Comment: @VictorQuezada thank you for the observation. That is right. I forgot the sum. Already edit :) Further observations are welcomed.